# Restore current approve version REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, version-history

Is there a way to restore **current approved** version using REST? I managed to get the number of versions but I could not figure out how to identify the version number of the **current approved** version. First thing, I retrieved the {ID} of the **rejected** item to use on:

```
var verUri = webAbsUrl + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('Staff List')/Items(" + rejId + ")/versions;
```

Then I tried retrieving the version ID and approval status

```
var ajaxVer = $.ajax({
url: verUri,
async: false,
method: "GET",
headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
success: function (data) {
    verCount = data.d.results.length;
    verNum = data.d.results[0].OData__UIVersionString;
    verStat = data.d.results[0].OData__ModerationStatus;
```

`verCount` provides the correct count but i could not figure out how to retrieve the version Number and Approval Status. I also tried using `data.d.results[0].Id`.

I was hoping I could do this dynamically rather than **approver** manually restoring the last approved version.

References:
[Restore a previous version of a ListItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/listitemversion_restore?view=odsp-graph-online)
[Listing versions of a ListItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/listitem_list_versions?view=odsp-graph-online)